# Datagridview, binding source, and invalid operation error

Tags: c#, binding, datagrid, invalidoperationexception

```
 foreach (Listing s in fx)
            {
                ListingBindingSource.Add(s);
            }
```

This in my code causes the following error:

Invalid operation error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Now i checked, I am running this on the main thread.

Also, it was working before. What changed recently is i changed Listing members, two of them, from int to string. I thought if i delete Listbindingsource and remake it, it would automatically change that. But it seems i have to do something else. Can anyone shed some light here.
ListBindsource is the datasource to a datagridview.
thanks

****SOLUTION***************

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  Listing s1 = new  Listing();
             ListingBindingSource.Add(s1);
}
```

for some reason this added it. When the form was created for some reason null was being passed into the bindingsource. why, i don't know.

Some additional info:

If i remove the bindingsource as a datasource of the gridview, the error vanishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.add.aspx) method refers the call to the underlying list's Add method.

The internal list must contain **homogenous** types. If the DataSource property has not already been set, then the first object added to the list defines the type for the list"

Comment: I went through the wizard to create the bindingsource. It's linked to my object so the internal list is List<Listing>

Comment: That is different that my problem.

Comment: Can you post code for Listings?I try to reproduce that on my m/c.

Comment: ListingBindingSource.Clear(); and then try ListingBindingSource.Add() or ListingBindingSource.Datasource =fx and ya lastely that null may causing the exception.